# PHP Zend Lucene Search Query with multiple criteria fail

Tags: php, zend-lucene

Zend Lucene Search Document

```
Lucene Document
    pk:Keyword
    category_id:Keyword
    title:UnStored
    description:UnStored
```

This is my string query "java lucene AND +category_id:7".
Result here:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pk] => 209
            [category_id] => 7
            [id] => 0
            [score] => 0.40750848701418
        )
   [1] => Array
        (
            [pk] => 225
            [category_id] => 7
            [id] => 3
            [score] => 0.30750848701619
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [pk] => 211
            [category_id] => 8 ====>>> WRONG!!! 
            [id] => 2
            [score] => 0.37152213415004
        )

)
```

---

Can you do a Query search on the category_id = 7 only??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had solved this problem by using Zend Query Parsing

```
$strQuery = Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_QueryParser::parse('java lucene');

$cateTerm  = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Index_Term(7 , 'category_id');
$cateQuery = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Term($cateTerm);

$query = new Zend_Search_Lucene_Search_Query_Boolean();
$query->addSubquery($strQuery, true /* required */);
$query->addSubquery($cateQuery, true /* required */);
```

Results will be only in category_id = 7 :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing it here, I was pulling my hair about the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `AND +category_id:7` from you query, what you want is a filter since `+category_id:7` is not needed as a ranked value.

I don't know how to implement it with `Zend_Lucene` but in solr I used to pass fq parameter, this may give you a hint :)

Filtering is a process that constrains the search space and allows only a subset of documents to be considered for search hits. You can use this feature to implement search-within-search results. Lucene comes with various built-in filters such as BooleanFilter, CachingWrapperFilter, ChainedFilter, DuplicateFilter, PrefixFilter, QueryWrapperFilter, RangeFilter, RemoteCachingWrapperFilter, SpanFilter, etc.(**THE NATIVE JAVA VERSION**) Filter can be passed to IndexSearcher's search method to filter documents that match the filter criteria.

Comment: I had solved this problem by using [Zend Query Parsing](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.searching.html)
Thank you for your answer.